# How to retrieve contact photo in Android?

Tags: android, android-contacts

## Retrieving a contact's photo without contactId

I'm having difficulty retrieving a contact's photo using only his/her phone-number.
I followed the official Android example on using "ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo". Unfortunately, the contactId parameter is required.

I successfully manage to retrieve the image in the end by using the following code:

```
long contactId = 0;
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));

Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
            new String[] { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID },
            null, null, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    contactId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
}
Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);

InputStream contactPhotoInputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(context.getContentResolver(), contactUri);

return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(contactPhotoInputStream);
```

However, as one can see, I have to query the contactId first. My question is now, if it is possible to directly query the contact's image?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but you can try

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI};
String where = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " = ?";

//You can use ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER
// depending on how the number is formatted

///the format of the phone number is important
String whereArgs = phoneNumber;

Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, where, whereArgs, null);
```

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately, I could not get this to work. I guess I'll stick to my current implementation.

Comment: @Patrick I've tried it and it does work. The formatting of the number is important for this to work. Look at my edit.